# How does one prove the Taylor's Theorem by the Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)+ \frac{1}{2} f''(c)(b-a)^2
$$

which I do believe is a specialized form of the Taylor's Theorem when you plug in $b$ and $a$ into the appropriate spots.  I think you can approach this by proving the Lagrangian remainder is the same, but it doesn't seem all that intuitive.

Comment: do you mean "$+\frac12\color{#C00000}{f''(c)}(b-a)^2$"?

Comment: yes.  that's what i meant.

Comment: I suggest reading Walter Rudin's proof of the theorem about Taylor's polynomial in *Principles of mathematical analysis*. You'll discover that the proof requires just Lagrange's theorem, a very particular case of Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function
$$
g(x)=f(x)-\left[f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)\right]-\frac{f(b)-\left[f(a)+(b-a)f'(a)\right]}{(b-a)^2}(x-a)^2
$$
Since $g(a)=0$ and $g(b)=0$, the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says there is a $c_1\in(a,b)$ so that $g'(c_1)=0$.
$$
g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(a)-\frac{f(b)-\left[f(a)+(b-a)f'(a)\right]}{(b-a)^2}(x-a)
$$
Since $g'(a)=0$ and $g'(c_1)=0$, the Mean Value Theorem says there is a $c_2\in(a,c_1)$ so that $g''(c_2)=0$. That is,
$$
0=f''(c_2)-2\frac{f(b)-\left[f(a)+(b-a)f'(a)\right]}{(b-a)^2}
$$
this, becomes
$$
f(b)=f(a)+(b-a)f'(a)+\frac12(b-a)^2f''(c_2)
$$

Comment: is there a way to do it without integration, and perhaps use the cauchy's mean value theorem more?

Comment: @mvgwpemb: I have added an approach that uses two applications of the MVT to get the answer.

Comment: g(b) doesn't seem to be zero to me

Comment: typo (and two following copies) fixed

Answer (score 1):

I answered the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750906/first-order-lagrange-remainder-using-ordinary-mvt/751398#751398) using the function

$$g(x)=f(b)-f(x)-(b-x)f'(x)-\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^2[f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)f'(a)]$$

In general, if

$$F_n(x)=f(b)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(x)(b-x)^k}{k!}$$

Then you can let

$$g_n(x)=F_n(x)-\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^nF_n(a)$$

Differentiate, factor out $\frac{n(b-x)^{n-1}}{(b-a)^n}$, and apply the mean value theorem. This will prove the $(n-1)$th order analogue of the mean value theorem, i.e.

$$f(b)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)(b-a)^k}{k!}+\frac{f^{(n)}(c)(b-a)^n}{n!}$$

for some $a<c<b$.

Comment: (+1) I have the same $g(x)$. I was going to mention the extensibility to higher orders, but I thought the second order might be enough complexity for now. The general case follows pretty easily from understanding the second order case.

Comment: @robjohn Because of Siminore's comment on the OP's question, I checked Rudin's proof after posting mine. It is pretty much the same argument, but I like his presentation better. It makes the higher order cases more apparent and there isn't the same difficulty with differentiating $g_n(x)$ and factoring out $\frac{n(b-x)^{n-1}}{(b-a)^n}$.

Comment: I figured Rudin's proof would be similar. It has that feel. However, his proofs often border on being too slick sometimes. As long as the derivatives at $a$ are all $0$ and the $(x-a)^n$ term added matches at $x=b$, the root zipper for $g^{(k)}(c_k)=0$ does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$g(y)=f(b)-(f(y)+f'(y)(b-y))-z(b-y)^2$$
where z is chosen such that $g(a)=0$ i.e:
$$z(b-a)^2=f(b)-(f(a)+f'(a)(b-a))   \ \ \ \ (1) $$
Now we have:
$$g(a)=g(b)=0$$
It follows from Rolle's theorem that
$$ \exists c \in ]a,b[, g'(c)=0$$
This is the desired result noticing that the last equation set the value $\frac {f"(c)} {2}$ for $z$